# How to backup database schema in Azure data explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am working on project, where I need to copy the database from one cluster to another cluster in Azure data explorer. Is there any KQL query for this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the a combination of the following control commands:

1. [.show database schema as csl script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-schema-database#show-database-schema-as-csl-script)

   - Should be invoked on the cluster in which the source database exists.
2. [.execute database script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script)

   - Should be invoked on the cluster in which the target database exists.

You'll need to copy the output of (1) as the script argument for (2).

For example:

```
.execute database script <|
   .alter database MyDB policy retention @'{"SoftDeletePeriod":"30.00:00:00","Recoverability":"Enabled"}'
   .alter database MyDB policy caching hotdata=time(12.00:00:00) hotindex=time(12.00:00:00)
   .create-merge table MyTable (a:string, b:int, c:string) 
   ... the rest of the output ...
```

Comment: I am not sure, how to use it with this combination. Can you provide sample KQL query for this. it would be helpful.

Comment: I tried this query,                                                                                                        
".execute database script <|

.show database ingestiontest schema as csl script"                                                              but it is not working.

Comment: Please see the example in the updated answer